# authentication in spring security case insensitive

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i found that in my app the security with spring security does not check the case of my usernames at loging.

I have this code:

```
        authBuilder
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM Utenti WHERE username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, role FROM Utenti WHERE username = ?");
```

I dont know why when i use different particular cases for the username, the authentication of spring permits all.
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caused by your DB schema definition. Please check the types of your database columns. By default, Spring provides a schema for H2 which uses type VARCHAR_IGNORECASE. The schema can be adapted though, depending on your requirements and your specific database.

- Spring Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/appendix/database-schema.html
- H2 Type VARCHAR_IGNORECASE: http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type

Comment: I use Mysql and my table is created with:

    username        varchar(100)  not null,
    password        varchar(100)  not null,

What should I change?